# Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при выборе элемента, через комбобокс, он в переменную выводил индекс её, и потом в условие но это не работает

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6, qcombobox

Если конкретнее пытаюсь сделать так, то при выборе элемента, через комбобокс, в данном случае формы фигуры, например круг, выводилась табличка ввода с кнопкой, в которую человек бы вводил значения радиуса, при квадрате, x и y, и т.д.

У меня программа отказывается читать индекс вообще, я через условие пытаюсь проверить, никак. 
Делал по гайду из PySide6. Как быть?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QDialog, QComboBox,
                               QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel)
import math


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.combobox1 = boxshit()
        self.combobox2 = boxshit1()
        self.r=Form3()
        self.x=Form()
        self.y=Form2()
        self.h=Form4()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.x)
        layout.addWidget(self.y)
        layout.addWidget(self.r)
        layout.addWidget(self.h)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox1)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox2)
        self.r.hide()
        self.x.hide()
        self.y.hide()
        self.h.hide()
        print(self.combobox2.z)
        if self.combobox2.z == 0 or self.combobox2.z == 4:
            self.r.show()
            self.x.hide()
            self.y.hide()
            self.h.hide()
            self.setLayout(layout)
            print(self.combobox2.z)
        if self.combobox2.z == 1 or self.combobox2.z == 2:
            self.x.show()
            self.y.show()
            self.r.hide()
            self.h.hide()
            self.setLayout(layout)
            print(self.combobox2.z)
        if self.combobox2.z == 3:
            self.x.hide()
            self.y.hide()
            self.r.hide()
            self.h.show()
            self.setLayout(layout)
            print(self.combobox2.z)
        self.setLayout(layout)



class boxshit(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(boxshit, self).__init__()
        self.index = 0
        self.z = -1
        self.combobox = QComboBox()
        self.combobox.addItems(["Площадь", "Периметр", "Объем"])
        self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.index_changed)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def index_changed(self, index):
        self.z=index
        print(index)


class boxshit1(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(boxshit1, self).__init__()
        self.index = 0
        self.z=-1
        self.combobox = QComboBox()
        self.combobox.addItems(["Круг", "Квадрат", "Треугольник", "Куб", "Шар"])
        self.combobox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.index_changed)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox)
        self.setLayout(layout)
    def index_changed(self, index):
        self.z=index
        print(index)


class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.der = QLabel("ЗАфигачить X")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("")
        self.button = QPushButton("X = ...")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.der)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        if self.button.clicked.connect:
            d = self.edit.text()
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form2(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.der = QLabel("ЗАфигачить Y")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("")
        self.button = QPushButton("Y = ...")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.der)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        if self.button.clicked.connect:
            d = self.edit.text()
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form3(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form3, self).__init__(parent)
        self.der = QLabel("ЗАфигачить Радиус")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("")
        self.button = QPushButton("R = ...")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.der)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        if self.button.clicked.connect:
            d = self.edit.text()
        self.setLayout(layout)


class Form4(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form4, self).__init__(parent)
        self.der = QLabel("ЗАфигачить Ребро")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("")
        self.button = QPushButton("H = ...")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.der)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        if self.button.clicked.connect:
            d = self.edit.text()
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dropbox = MainWindow()
    dropbox.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

> void [**QComboBox::addItem(const QString &text, const QVariant &userData = QVariant())**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#addItem)
>
> Добавляет элемент в поле со списком с заданным текстом и содержащий указанные пользовательские данные (хранящиеся в Qt::UserRole). 
> Элемент добавляется в список существующих элементов.

> QVariant [**QComboBox::itemData(int index, int role = Qt::UserRole)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#itemData) const
>
> Возвращает данные для данной роли по заданному индексу в поле со списком или недопустимый QVariant, если для этой роли нет данных.

```
import sys
import math
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, 
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QDialog, QComboBox, QMainWindow, QWidget, 
    QLabel)
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        
        # ... напишите самостоятельно


class Form2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form2, self).__init__(parent)
        
        # ... напишите самостоятельно


class Form3(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, index_cb2, index, parent=None):        # !!! + index_cb2, index
        super(Form3, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.index_cb2 = index_cb2                            # !!! +++
        self.index = index                                    # !!! +++
        self.parent = parent                                  # !!! +++
        
        self.der = QLabel("Введите радиус")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("")
        
        self.button = QPushButton("R = ...")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_form3)        # !!! +++
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.der)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
    
    def button_form3(self):                                   # !!! +++
        try:
            r = float(self.edit.text())
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Внимание', 
                'Ввелите правильно значение радиуса')
            return
            
        if self.index == 1 and self.index_cb2 == 1:
            self.parent.label.setText(
                f"Площадь круга = {math.pi * (r ** 2)}; \n(радиус = {r})")
        elif self.index == 1 and self.index_cb2 == 5:
            self.parent.label.setText(
                f"Объем шара = {4 / 3 * math.pi * r ** 3}; \n(радиус = {r})")                
        elif self.index == 2 and self.index_cb2 == 1:
            self.parent.label.setText(
                f"Периметр круга = {2 * math.pi * r}; \n(радиус = {r})")
        self.close()


class Form4(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, index, parent=None):
        super(Form4, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.der = QLabel("Введите Ребро")
        self.edit = QLineEdit("")
        self.button = QPushButton("H = ...")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_form4)
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.der)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        
    def button_form4(self):    
        try:
            r = float(self.edit.text())
        except:
            msg = QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Внимание', 
                'Ввелите правильно значение ребра')
            return
            
        if self.index == 1:
            self.parent.label.setText(
                f"Объем куба = {r ** 3}; \n(ребро = {r})")
        self.close()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        
        self.index_cb2 = 0

        self.combobox2 = QComboBox()
# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.combobox2.addItem('Выберите фигуру', ["Выберите что расчитать", ])
        self.combobox2.addItem('Круг', ["Площадь", "Периметр",])
        self.combobox2.addItem('Квадрат', ["Площадь", "Периметр",])
        self.combobox2.addItem('Треугольник', ["Площадь", "Периметр",])
        self.combobox2.addItem('Куб', ["Объем", ])
        self.combobox2.addItem('Шар', ["Объем", ])
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.combobox2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateComboBox2)
        
        self.combobox1 = QComboBox()
        self.combobox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateComboBox1)
        
        self.label = QLabel()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox2)
        layout.addWidget(self.combobox1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def updateComboBox1(self, index):
        if index < 1:
            self.label.clear()
            return
        print(f'index_cb2={self.index_cb2}; index={index}')        
        if (self.index_cb2 == 1 or self.index_cb2 == 5) :
            self.r = Form3(self.index_cb2, index, self)
            aa = self.r.exec()
        elif self.index_cb2 == 4:
            self.r = Form4(index, self)
            aa = self.r.exec()  
        elif self.index_cb2 == 2 or self.index_cb2 == 3:
            pass                                        # ... напишите самостоятельно 

    def updateComboBox2(self, index):
        self.index_cb2 = index
        self.combobox1.clear()
        self.combobox1.addItem('Выберите что расчитать')
        items = self.combobox2.itemData(index)                          # !!! +++
        if items:
            self.combobox1.addItems(items)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(300, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]